Proving the minimum t-norm is a joint possibility distribution
A t-norm is an operator $T:[0,1]^2\rightarrow[0,1]$ which is comutative, monotonic, associative and  has 1 as an identity element, that is, $T(1,x)=T(x,1)=x$.
A joint possibility distribution (JPD) of the fuzzy numbers $A_{1},\cdots,A_{n}$ is a fuzzy subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $A_{i}(x_{i})=\max_{x_{j}\in\mathbb{R},j\neq i}C(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}),$ for every $i.$
$T(x,y)=\min\{x,y\}$ is a t-norm, and apparently, a JPD, too. That is, given two fuzzy numbers $A,B,$ we have $\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\min\{A(x),B(y)\}=B(y)$ and $\max_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\min\{A(x),B(y)\}=A(x).$  But I can't seem to prove this last bit. The references I'm using only stablish that it's true,
and move on. I'd like to see a proof of the statement, if possible.
